# bests book of representation theory for algebraic number theorists

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation, galois-representations

I am looking for some of the best books on representation theory for an algebraic number theorists> I would prefer a book that is more number theoretical (e.g, galois representations, p adic representations), thanks in advance.

Comment: probably you would do well to look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13282/good-algebraic-number-theory-books.